# how to find latest created folder in dir

Tags: perl

Can anybody give me some help for figuring out the problem below.

Here are some facts:

- I am using Windows XP.
- We have the directory `/abc5/def/ghi/dcl_201107_hy79u_02`. In which the inner sub-directory name (the `dcl_201207_hy79u_02` part) changes every week using the following rule:

  ```
  dcl_<year><week>_hy79u_<some_number>
  ```

  e.g. `dcl_201208_hy79u_05` for the 8th week and `dcl_201209_hy79u_06` for the 9th week.

  As far as we are concerned, the `<some_number>` part (ie 02, 05 or 06) is some random number.
- Under this directory there will be 60 files and those file names would be like:

  `dcl_201207_hy79u_02_epoc32_include_internal.zip`

Now what I am trying to implement is this:

Every week a new dir is created on FTP server and we have to copy some 64 files out of 100 files. How I am proceeding is to copy all the 64 files names in a text file and reading each line and pulling the file I want. The problem is that I am not able to find the latest created folder and also I am not able to modify those files name according to the week.
I tried to use template as suggested by this community but I failed as beging very new to Perl :(

So I am trying to replace the string `dcl_201207_hy79u_02` in every file wherever I get it.

e.g. for the 8th week dir name would be  `dcl_201208_hy79u_05` then replace this string in every file.

Comment: Over FTP, or on a local filesystem? The `stat` function returns (among other things) the creation date, but if the names are completely predictable, you don't need that.

Comment: Over local system because i am keeping my script and txt file on my local pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the week number in `$w`, the function `sprintf("week%02dsuffix", $w)` returns `week01suffix` when `$w` is 1, etc.